# Spark streaming could not read data from write ahead log record when Receiver failed and WAL is stored in s3

Tags: spark-streaming, wal

Here is the error log -

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not read data from write ahead
>   log record
>   FileBasedWriteAheadLogSegment(s3n://*****/checkpoint/receivedData/20/log-1439298698600-1439298758600,13678,5069)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.WriteAheadLogBackedBlockRDD.org$apache$spark$streaming$rdd$WriteAheadLogBackedBlockRDD$$getBlockFromWriteAheadLog$1(WriteAheadLogBackedBlockRDD.scala:144)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.WriteAheadLogBackedBlockRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(WriteAheadLogBackedBlockRDD.scala:168)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.WriteAheadLogBackedBlockRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(WriteAheadLogBackedBlockRDD.scala:168)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.WriteAheadLogBackedBlockRDD.compute(WriteAheadLogBackedBlockRDD.scala:168)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.compute(UnionRDD.scala:87)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:277)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:244)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.util.FileBasedWriteAheadLog.read(FileBasedWriteAheadLog.scala:106)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.rdd.WriteAheadLogBackedBlockRDD.org$apache$spark$streaming$rdd$WriteAheadLogBackedBlockRDD$$getBlockFromWriteAheadLog$1(WriteAheadLogBackedBlockRDD.scala:141)
>           ... 22 more

NOTE: If HDFS is used as storage, read from WAL works fine.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like currently WAL is not supported with s3 and Spark team is working on WAL free configuration.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9215